# Slow transition to same page anchor with window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that is fully working. When I click a radio button it redirects the user to the next part of the web page (that is to: div id="profiel")

```
<script>
    $("input[name='gender']").change(function(){
      window.location = "#profiel";
  });
</script>
```

The radio button:

```
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender">    
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender">
```

I want the transition to the anchor tag to go slow. So that the page slowly scrolls down. Now it instantly goes to the #profiel section. I have seen this before I just do not know how to do it myself.

Comment: And you didn't google "website smooth scrolling" before asking here why exactly?

Comment: I was not familiar with the term 'smooth scrolling'

Comment: @RogierWijsman, you tried the solutions I have provided? How did it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<script>
    $("input[name='gender']").change(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#profiel").offset().top
        }, 2000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you for you time and effort!

Comment: Your welcome @RogierWijsman, happy to help. Thank you too for accepting my answer and voting it up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jquery plugin name  Nicescroll you can use that 
The code will be

```
$("input[name=gender]").change(function(){
  $('html').nicescroll()
  window.location = "#profiel";
```

});

Or if you want I guess adding transition :1s all ease-in-out in you css body  or   html   styling may help but I am not sure for this but that nicescroll plugin will work for sure

Comment: I went with the other answer. Thank you for your time and input!